# urlopen error unknown url type: b'https

Tags: python-3.6

i'm trying to extract data from a url using

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(str(self.url)).read()
```

and i'm getting the error

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: b'https>
```

if i try using

```
data = urlopen(urllib.parse.quote(str(self.url))).read()
```

i get the error

```
ValueError: unknown url type 'b%27https%3A//some.site.com/d/f/some.image.enc%27'
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Print out what the str() produces and check what self.url actually is

Comment: even after str() its prints out b"_https://some.site.com/d/f/some.image.enc"

Comment: So self.url is not a string or an object that would stringify itself. Check what type it is

Comment: Need to use `decode` to make it a string then

Comment: type of url is bytes before str(), and 'str' after the str()

Comment: solved it by using str(url)[2:] (to remove the b"), very ugly workaround, but it works